# How to dynamically get listIds from Enhanced Lists

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

my page having a list view

```
<apex:page>
  <apex:enhancedList  type="custom__c" height="300" listId="00BM0000000wSbc" />
</apex:page>
```

when i do package and install in different org, enhanced list is  not working, getting error because different listId.

How can we get dynamic listId ?

Comment: I have a workaround for this by remove listId:  <apex:enhancedList  type="custom__c" height="300"  />